# Ubuntu 16.04 menu outlook changed completely after a reboot

Tags: 16.04, menu

The outlook of my Ubuntu 16.04 menu changed completely and unexpectedly after a reboot.

It used to have a side-menu of items on the left, with instant access to search bar (top icon of that sidebar): [Menu outlook before reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Tsj.png)
\

Now it disappeared and is subbed by that tiny "Activities" option on top left, and simply a different top menu bar: [Menu outlook after reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SafGA.png)
\

What might've happened and how do I bring the original outlook back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the "before reboot" desktop is Unity, and the "after reboot" is some kind of Gnome.

Try to choose "Unity" at the login screen.

Comment: Thanks so much! I could hardly notice that tiny Settings wheel at the login screen.